# Scala Algebraic Data Types for file extension to format mapping

Tags: scala, case-class, algebraic-data-types

So I'm a total Scala noob and come from a rusty Java background and a primarily PHP+JavaScript one. 
I'm finding myself getting frustrated, because there are design patterns I want to implement in Scala but I have no idea how, WHich leads to a lot of reading, and never any programming.

Anyway so I am busy making a basic program to learn the ins and outs, and I am making a configuration file reader. What i need to do is map different formats to extensions, the trick being that different extensions such as `yaml` and `yml` map to the same format.

In java I would use `Enums` and control the mapping in the constructor. Pretty straight forward.

In scala ... not so much. First I discover that ADT (meaning Algebraic Data Types not Abstract Data Types) is a better alternative then the use of Enumeration (reasons for which are still not clear to me), and it works better with Java libraries (ironically, and I have no idea why.)

Next I discover the various formats of ADT, and as a beginner grasping all the concepts simultaneously is strenuous. I have managed to figure out that the `companion Objects` are similar to javascript in the sense that it is a single instantiation almost like a singleton and allows you to access the defined functions in a static context.

---

### Now back to the problem

I've written what I thought was a good idea, but the code looks cumbersome, verbose, and I can't figure out some use cases, and It appears from all my JS plugin writing I'm a bit of a namespacing nut that does well for logical separation but not conciseness in scala.

```scala
class ConfigManager {
  object Formats{
    case class Format(f: String){
      val format = f.toUpperCase()
    }
    case object Yaml extends Format("YAML")
    case object Xml  extends Format("XML")
    case object Json extends Format("JSON")
  }

  object Extensions {
    case class Extension(e: String) {
      val extension = e.toUpperCase()
    }
    case object Yaml extends Extension("YAML")
    case object Yml  extends Extension("YML")
    case object Xml  extends Extension("XML")
    case object Json extends Extension("JSON")
  }


  object Config {
    private sealed trait ConfigFormats {
      def f: Formats.Format
      def e : Extensions.Extension
    }
    case class ConfigFormat(f: Formats.Format, e: Extensions.Extension) 
            extends ConfigFormats (f, e)

    case object Yaml1 extends ConfigFormat(Formats.Yaml, Extensions.Yaml)
    case object Yaml2 extends ConfigFormat(Formats.Yaml, Extensions.Yml)
    case object Xml   extends ConfigFormat(Formats.Xml, Extensions.Xml)
    case object Json  extends ConfigFormat(Formats.Json, Extensions.Json)
  }

  //this looks nice, and useful, is concise and does what I want
  def readConfig(c: Config.ConfigFormat){
    c.f match {
      case Formats.Yaml => readConfigYaml()
      case Formats.Json => readConfigJson()
      case Formats.Xml  => readConfigXml()
      case _ => throw new Exception("Invalid Config format")
    }
  }

  //and this is where I lose the plot
  def setFormat(extension: String){
    val configFormat = new Extensions.Extension(discoveredFormat) match {
      case Config.????? => ????
    }
  }
}
```

---

So the obvious question is how bad exactly is my implementation, and what should I have done, and why? (I'm most concerned about the "Why")

Comment: You should use packages instead of objects. Then use polymorphism. And maybe you don't need so many types to accomplish your goal.

Comment: If you want to stay functional, try to make your methods return a value instead of making side-effects.

Comment: Many design patterns are of no use in Scala, because the problems they solve have disappeared.

Comment: So I have realised, but it doesn't mean that the "proper" way in scala comes naturally. 

To the point, I'm still curious to see an ADT implementation, and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala Enums are fine, you could define `Formats` and `Extensions` like this:

```
object Formats extends Enumeration {
  type Eny = Value
  val YAML, XML, JSON = Value
}
object Extensions extends Enumeration {
  type Eny = Value
  val YAML, YML, XML, JSON = Value
}
```

And if you want to a *map*, just use a *map*:

```
val configFormats: Map[Extensions.Value, Formats.Value] = Map(
  Extensions.YAML -> Formats.YAML,
  Extensions.YML  -> Formats.YAML,
  Extensions.XML  -> Formats.XML,
  Extensions.JSON -> Formats.JSON)
```

Then I'm not really sure of what your methods are supposed to do, but it looks like your `setFormat` could start like this:

```
def setFormat(extension: String): Unit = {
  val format: Formats.Value = configFormats(Extensions withName extension)
  ...
}
```

You see, just like Java :) If you describe better what you are trying to do we might be able to give you a more "idiomatic way".

Comment: I could not have asked for a better answer - The problem was between the 20 tabs I had open I was confused about what was the best practice, and the number of people recommending ADT instead of Enumerations was high. And that I wasn't quite grasping.